# conflicting packages - not installing wazuh-agent

Tags: wazuh

I want to add an agent in wazuh, but I'm having problems.

```
dpkg: regarding ./wazuh-agent-4.3.6.deb containing wazuh-agent:
 wazuh-agent conflicts with wazuh-manager
  wazuh-manager (version 4.3.6-1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive ./wazuh-agent-4.3.6.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing wazuh-agent
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ./wazuh-agent-4.3.6.deb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error attached, you are trying to install Wazuh Agent in a debian based machine where **Wazuh Manager is already installed, this is not possible.** You cannot have both Wazuh Agent and Wazuh Server installed in the same system.

To confirm this, what do you get in the machine when running the command `systemctl status wazuh-manager`?

-If you get the following message or a similar one then you have wazuh-manager installed

```
wazuh-manager.service - Wazuh manager
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wazuh-manager.service;
...
```

-If you get "`Unit wazuh-manager.service could not be found.`" then it is not installed.

Comment: yes when I run the command  ``systemctl status wazuh-agent``appear ``Unit wazuh-agent.service could not be found.``. What's the solution for that, so you can add an agent on wazuh?

Comment: Hi Ibnu, it is expected to get `Unit wazuh-agent.service could not be found` if you run `systemctl status wazuh-agent` since you are not able to install it, you are not able to install it because the Wazuh Manager is already installed in that system (you can confirm this by executing `systemctl status wazuh-manager`. If you want to remove Wazuh-manager and install Wazuh-agent, you can follow this article [Uninstall the Wazuh Server](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/uninstall/central-components.html#uninstall-the-wazuh-server) and then proceed to install the Wazuh Agent

Comment: Is there any way to install both Wazuh server and agent on the same linux machine?
thanks

Comment: Hi Dion, currently when you install the Wazuh Manager this one acts as Agent **ID 000**, so there is no need to try installing a Wazuh Agent in the same host and the host will warn you about this. You will be able to see the security relevant events from the Wazuh Manager in the section "Security Events" of the Wazuh Web UI, the agent.id field coming with the value 000.

The [issue 8695](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/8695) aims to separate the Wazuh Manager from the Wazuh Agent (ID 000), therefore I believe in a future it will make sense to install both packages in the same host